# Accessing flagged spots on geo-map

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, sapui5

I am creating a Selenium WebDriver test automation script (based on Java) which is testing a web-page with Geo-map. The Geo-map is displaying sales orders as separate flags. 
Selenium by itself cannot see the Geo-map and the flags located on it (only CANVAS element in DOM).

This is SAP-based web-application built using SAP GUI5 elements.

Is there any solution to be able to access Geo-map's flags if I know the ID of each sales order standing behind each flag on the Geo-map?

Comment: You either need an existing API into the CANVAS app or have the devs create/expose one for you. Once you get that, you can use Selenium to navigate pages and then use JSE to call the JS API to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks JeffC, for your comment. What exactly do you mean under "create/expose"?  Is it calling JS functions directly from the source code by means of JS Executor? Or is it creating some sort of additional midlleware that would give JS Executor control over Geo-Map flags?

Comment: The devs would need to expose an API to get/set whatever values you need to change. In Selenium, you would use JSE to call those methods to get/set the values, etc.